# c++ recursion in large number class

Tags: c++, class, recursion

I'm implementing a large-number library, and I'm stuck on a strange issue. I have a recursive implementation of multiplication, but the first recursive call doesn't even begin to resolve. Here's a portion of the code (this is inside the BigInt class):

```
BigInt multiply_utility(BigInt num1, BigInt num2)
{

    cout << "Location 1";

    if(num1.get_length() == 1)
    {
        if(num1.get(MAX-1) == 0 || num2.get(MAX-1) == 0)
            {
                BigInt zero;
                return zero;
            }
        BigInt temp = num2;

        for(int i = 1; i < num1.get(MAX-1); i++)
            num2 = temp.add(num2);

        return num2;
    }

    else if(num2.get_length() == 1)
    {
        if(num1.is_zero() || num2.is_zero())
        {
            BigInt zero;
            return zero;
        }
        BigInt temp = num1;

        for(int i = 1; i < num2.get(MAX-1); i++)
            num1 = temp.add(num1);

        return num1;
    }

    int m = max(num1.get_length(), num2.get_length());
    BigInt low1, low2, high1, high2;


    for(int i = MAX-num1.get_length(); i < MAX-(num1.get_length()/2); i++)
        low1.set((MAX-((MAX-(num1.get_length()/2))-i)) ,num1.get(i));
    low1.auto_set_length();


    for(int i = MAX-num2.get_length(); i < MAX-(num2.get_length()/2); i++)
        low2.set((MAX-((MAX-(num2.get_length()/2))-i)) ,num2.get(i));
    low2.auto_set_length();

    for(int i = MAX-(num1.get_length()/2); i < MAX; i++)
        high1.set(i,num1.get(i));
    high1.auto_set_length();

    for(int i = MAX-(num2.get_length()/2); i < MAX; i++)
        high2.set(i,num2.get(i));
    high2.auto_set_length();

    cout << "low1 = " << low1.str() << endl;
    cout << "high1 = " << high1.str() << endl;

    cout << "low2 = " << low2.str() << endl;
    cout << "high2 = " << high2.str() << endl;

    BigInt z0,z1,z2;
    BigInt handle;

    cout << "Location 2";
    z0 = multiply_utility(low1,low2);
    cout << "Location 3";

    z1 = multiply_utility(low1.add(high1),low2.add(high2));
    z2 = multiply_utility(high1,high2);



    BigInt a;

    a = z1.subtract(z2);
    a = a.subtract(z0);

    return (((z2.shift(m)).add(a.shift(m/2))).add(z0));

    /*
    return (z2*10^(m))+(（z1-z2-z0）*10^(m/2))+(z0)
    */
}
```

It prints "location 1" then "location 2", but does *not* print "location 1" again as it should with a recursive call. Any idea what could be wrong? Could it be that it's a class method function?

Comment: What a mess is that function...

Comment: I'm writing it in a rush, I could easily make it neater. Regardless of the style, the recursion problem shouldn't be happening.

Comment: @Nathan: Could you try adding a `std::endl` after each `cout`. That will cause stdout to flush the stream which may be your problem.

Comment: @Nathan *"I could easily make [this question] neater"*  Prove it.

Comment: Too much of a rush, neatness isn't my priority in the least. Anyhow, it's more obfuscated than messy.

Comment: "Anyhow, it's more obfuscated than messy".  I'm totally stealing that for the next code review...

Answer (score 1):

Can you not put a break point in there to debug it?

I suspect that the code hit a `return` at some point and pop out of this function, thus, does not display "location..." as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Okay everyone, it seems to be a stack overflow. The objects I were creating were too large to all fit on the stack and recursion taxed it too much. Thanks anyhow!